# How to remove a member from Family Link

Tags: google-account, google-family-link

I created a family with two kids:

1. child that is under 13 years
2. child that is above 13 years

I got to the point I would like to delete a kid from the group, thus I searched google help and found [this](https://support.google.com/families/answer/6286986?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=android).

If I try to follow section called '**How to remove someone from your family group**', I keep having these problems:

- Web browser: Click on family member do not have option to remove from group for both children
- Play store app: Missing setting from point 4 (More > Remove Member > Remove) for both children
- Family link app: Missing remove member option for both children
- Google one app: No manage family option

I created a question on Google support https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/85062815 but it remains unanswered for some time.

If I try to delete the group it says: Can't delete a family group with members under 15 (this is limit in my country). I will keep this as a last option to temporary shift both children's age above 15 ([link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1333913)) to remove this group, however I would like to know how to really remove a child from Family Link group.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. It might me on-topic in [android.se], [apple.se]

Comment: From my point of view - this is exactly about using a web application (Google's Family Link). There is functionality, that is not working and I would like to know, how does it work...It is definitely not android specific

Comment: Not all the Google apps are web apps. In this specific case the question is not related to using a web app but about using an Android or iOS app. (the referred help article in the question offers two versions, one for Android the other for iOS)

Comment: This is not true. I am referring in the first point to deleting a user from a family in **Web Browser**, thus you cannot consider as Android or iOS question. The rest are just alternatives.

Comment: The referred help article has two tabs, one for Androd and another for iOS, that is true, but also you are right, the section about removing a user mentions the use of web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **remove the kid under 13** from your family group, you must delete their Google Account, as explained here:
https://support.google.com/families/answer/6286986#zippy=%2Cremove-a-supervised-child-from-your-family-group
[image]

The procedure to delete the Google Account of your kid under 13 can be performed from the Family Link menu, and is explained here:
https://support.google.com/families/answer/9182020#delete-child-account&zippy=%2Cuse-your-computer
[image]